# C++ class and empty arrays

Tags: c++, arduino, neural-network

Hello I try to implement a little machine learning for Arduino. It should run on a x86 also to make it easier to debug and train it.

Unfortunately there is some problem (with memory I guess).
If I try to use something like eg. `weights[1][1]` I get segmentation faults. Valgrind or gdb show the memory is null.

My guess is that `layers = new Layer[5];` causes this empty memory and `layers[1] = Layer(preLayer, 10, afunc);` does not set the memory as I would expect it.

I found some hints to implement something like `Layer& Layer::operator=(const Layer& other) // copy assignment` but I don't understand why. I even tried to fix it this way but this lead to new problems.

Question:
Is there a way to avoid "empty" Layers? I would like to avoid `Layer();` and `layers = new Layer[5];` at all if sensible.

```
//afunc is a function
layers = new Layer[5];
Layer *preLayer = &layers[0];
layers[1] = Layer(preLayer, 10, afunc);
```

Layer.h

```
class Layer
{
    public:
        Layer *preLayer;
        float **weights;
        int weightSize;
        float *biases;
        float *neurons;
        int neuronsSize;
        void (*afunc)(float *);
        Layer();
        Layer(Layer *input, int outputs, void (*afunc)(float *));
        ~Layer();
        void calculateNeurons();
    private:
        Layer(const Layer &layertoCopy); // not implemented
};
```

Layer.c

```
Layer::Layer() {}
Layer::Layer(Layer *preLayer, int neuronsSize, void (*afunc)(float *)): preLayer(preLayer), neuronsSize(neuronsSize), afunc(afunc)
{
    neurons = new float[this->neuronsSize]();
    if(this->preLayer) {
        weightSize = (*this->preLayer).neuronsSize;
        weights = new float*[this->neuronsSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < this->neuronsSize; ++i) {
            weights[i] = new float[weightSize];
        }
        biases = new float[this->neuronsSize]();
    }
}

Layer::~Layer()
{
}
```

Comment: The default `ctor` here is invalid, it leaves memory randomly initialized, so You can't relay on member variables values: e.g. `if(layer.weights)`  will probably always be true (even though You have never initialized it). The `dtor` is also invalid, since You do not release the allocated memory. 
If possible use std::vector<> and smart_pointers here.

Comment: Why do you mention and tag this `Arduino` ? On an Arduino you will run easily into memory problems, if you don't check for errors on `new`.

Comment: Well I should run on an Arduino. Especially if I run in a problem on Arduino it's important to address this with the limits the Arduino platform has (eg. no libC, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your sample code,

```
layers[1] = Layer(preLayer, 10, afunc);
```

you have two problems. In the non-default constructor, you check

```
if(this->preLayer)
```

You have sent in something which is not null, but doesn't initialise anything.

```
&layers[1] = new Layer(0, 10, afunc);
```

should avoid this.

However, if you make a `std::vector` instead of the c-style array you can `push_back` new layers, without having to use the pointer.

Also, if you want to use pointers, make the destructor `delete` them appropriately.

Comment: Ok I will try to use std::vector

Answer (score 0):

Your layers were made with default constructor first when you wrote "layers = new Layer[5]". Maybe try with:

```
Layer** layers = new Layer*[5];
Layer* prevLayer = nullprt;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    layers[i]=new Layer(prevLayer,10,afunc);
    prevLayer=layers[i];
}
```